# fetching a tree for a particular node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want all children of a given node with their interconnection with each other. For example A->B->C->D is a tree and I want a tree from A(starting point), Output should be 
A->B
B->C
C->D
and not as
A->B
A->C
A->D

`MATCH (fromNode:Part{partNumber:"100"})-[:HAS_BOM_PROPERTY]->(BomNode:BomProperties)-[*]->(toNode:Part) return fromNode{.*}, toNode{.*},BomNode{.*}`

I am using above query, it is giving me all the nodes connected with partNumber 100 at all levels but I want them along with their relationship with respective parent element and not all directly connected to partNumber 100.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this::

```
MATCH path=(fromNode:Part{partNumber:"100"})-[:HAS_BOM_PROPERTY]->(BomNode:BomProperties)-[*]->(toNode:Part)
// get all the relationships
UNWIND relationships(path) AS rel
// remove duplicates
WITH DISTINCT rel
RETURN startNode(rel) AS fromNode,endNode(rel) AS toNode
```

Comment: here I am getting things but what I am expecting is the middle node along with start and end node...which is bomNode here... for example:- A->b->C where  A and C are nodes of part type and b is of bomProperties type. Here I need path from A->C along with b as bomNode. And thank you for above suggestion It'll take me one step further.